# Elderly cat has eye closed shut and she won't eat

Tags: cats, vision

My cat is 18 years old.  When I went outside to the backyard (where she prefers to be)to check on her I noticed that her eye was closed shut and the same side of her face is swollen.  She won't eat or drink anything.  What should I do?

Comment: Could you possibly add a photo of what the cat's face looks like?

Comment: Related question [How long can a healthy cat go without food?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5593)

Answer (score 3):

You should take her to the vet. She likely has some type of wound (insect sting, infected laceration) and a vet will be able to tell what type of wound it is and how to treat it.

Further, if she hasn't been eating or drinking for longer than a day, she may be suffering from some of the [complications of anorexia](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/6366/224), such as dehydration or even hepatic lipidosis. These complications are *serious* and *life-threatening*, especially in an older cat.