# Why is my cat drooling and unable to eat food and clean itself?

Tags: cats, health, eating

My cat is unable to eat for the last 1 week.  I don't know what the problem is, but her mouth is drooling a lot.  She is also unable to clean herself.  I guess there is some problem in her mouth, but I do not understand what it is.  I am planning to take her to the vet, but it's difficult to take her, so if I can get a home remedy, then that would be easier, or at least can someone suggest what the problem is?

Comment: Cats not eating for 2 or more days is a medical emergency [How long can a healthy cat go without food?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/how-long-can-a-healthy-cat-go-without-food)

Comment: Yes,you need to take this cat to the vet immediately.

Answer (score 16):

There is not enough information provided to get a diagnosis.  **This appears to be an animal in direct distress.  You need to take the cat to the veterinarian immediately** for diagnosis and treatment.

There is no home remedy we can supply on this forum that would resolve your issue.

**Take your cat to the vet immediately**, especially if the cat has not eaten for this long.

Answer (score 5):

Take your cat to the vet!

This is likely serious, as the other answer said.

Cats can develop severe liver problems if they go without food for too long and one week is enough to get me very, very worried about your cat. A week without food is a serious matter. The underlying cause is serious in and of itself and not eating will have cause additional problems.

No, there is no home remedy.

For one thing, how can there be a remedy when the issue hasn't been diagnosed?

Get the cat to the vet. Do whatever you need to do to get her to a vet NOW!

If one of our cats stopped eating for longer than a day or day and a half, we would take him or her to the vet for evaluation.

None of us here are vets and even if some of us are quite experienced in matter pertaining to cats, we don't have the training to diagnose your cat remotely and I would not even try if I was there. A vet needs to check your cat out.

Even a vet could not diagnose your cat based upon what you have said or even if you a gave very detailed description. A competent vet would never dream of diagnosing a cat only on the basis of owner described symptoms. The vet has to see, handle, examine the cat to determine what is wrong.

Take the cat to the vet!

Not eating for a week is a very dangerous situation. The underlying cause has to be determined and treated absolutely as soon as is possible.

SimonT

Answer (score 1):

just had our cat put down on these sympthoms, turned out to be cat aids of some sort and the tounge just looks like its falling apart therefore no eating or grooming. witch started only 2 days ago then the drooling started today and we took him to the vet who made the diagonosis. if your cat has any of these symptoms please take it to a vet immediatly.

Answer (score 0):

Drooling can be a symptom of toxicity associated with insecticides, such as flea treatment products. Other symptoms are loss of balance, lethargy, diarrhea, in serious cases, tremors.
If you are using such a product (or any non-critical substance, actually), you should stop.
You should go to your vet in any case, your cat is in danger.

Answer (score -1):

We have the same situation with my cat. He has also stopped eating and drinking, lethargic and drooling while sleeping. Planning to go to the Vet but I don't have enough money. So I tried many different home remedies to survive my cat.

**Please try this first so that your cat not starve to death:**

Blend the pumpkin, potato and chicken liver into a liquid and feed him using a syringe. Force feeding him can help to back his energy. Don't forget the Water with Dextrose powder as well.

Comment: Welcome to pets! This site is a Q&A site where every answer is supposed to be informative and stay helpful for a long time. Therefore any appeal for donations is strictly forbidden. If you cannot afford a vet, please take a look at this post: [I can't afford vet treatment, what are my options?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/18810/12501)

Comment: Do you have any sources to back your ideas for home remedies? Please add them.