# Cat's behaviour when dying

Tags: cats, behavior, death

I have heard that cats tend to stop eating, and crawl under a couch or bed when they are dying. Understandably, I am now irrationally terrified every time my cat spends more than 1/2 an hour under a bed, or misses a meal. Is this actually true?

Comment: This question is about a different situation, but the answers will help you know when to worry about your cat missing a meal. [How long can a healthy cat go without food?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/q/5593/224)

Comment: When cats spend over an hour under the bed it may also mean that they are just trying to have some of their own peace. One of our cats does that on busy days (when general cleaning in our house is going on etc) and goes out after. When I peek under the bed, the cat would be sleeping peacefully. Don't be so worried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not especially. Those may indicate the cat isn't feeling well, but most reasons a cat might not be feeling well are not fatal, and there are other reasons a cat might feel like hiding or not be immediately interested in food.