# 12 y/o cat not eating/drinking

Tags: cats

Yesterday (Friday) I took him to the vet because he has been eating less and less this past week. Thursday he ate a little, but not much. Plus he's lost weightand has loose stool.. They gave him fluids and a shot to help with nausea because he threw up a little during the night. I was given some meds but told it will only help the symptoms and probably won't do much. He has an ultrasound Monday at 8:30am.

Now... Ever since we've come home he just sits around. He still hasn't eaten or drank water. I've tried giving him his favorite wet food, nothing. I boiled some chicken and when I held a piece up to his mouth he almost seemed interested in the food but at the last minute didn't take a bite.

He isn't hiding, just laying where he usually does. Right now he's sitting next to me purring. Eyes are clear and nose is fine.

My dilemma is I can't decide if I should pay the extra money and go to the emergency vet since he still hasn't eaten. It's been over 24 hours and come Monday (if he still doesn't eat) will be 60.

I guess I'd just like some input and ideas to get him to eat and drink.

Comment: If your cat has not eaten in 24 hours it is medical emergency. Also we have several similar questions I am voting to close this as duplicate of one of them.

Comment: See also http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/how-long-can-a-healthy-cat-go-without-food