# My cat was fine yesterday. And today shes not eating or drinking

Tags: cats, health, diseases

I have a cat. She's about 6 months old. She was fine yesterday. She went into hiding last night. I found her today. And she seems really sick. Her behavior is completely different. Her back legs seem really sore. She won't eat or drink. And her breathing is a lot faster then it's supposed to be. Please help me help her.

Comment: Hi james. I think its something else. Ive been hand feeding her water through a syringe. But it seems to be doing nothing. Her back legs are going from underneath her. I was feeling around the back leg area. And she seems to be in pain. Why i dont know. Ive looked for a tick. And cant find one. Shes very spoilt. Her behavior has completely changed shes not my cat. Shes hissing at me. Shes giving up  and wants to hide and be alone.

Comment: You say her back legs seem really sore.  By any chance did she recently receive a vaccine via injection?

Answer (score 6):

You need to take the cat to the vet today.If she was only not eating you could wait until tomorrow for the vet.  Related [How long can a healthy cat go without food?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/how-long-can-a-healthy-cat-go-without-food)

Comment: Are there 24hr vets

Comment: There are 24 hour vets, but you will need to search in your area.

Comment: Most SPCA organizations have a hot line that can connect you to emergency/off-hours vet service; some, such as the MSPCA, run their own emergency services and hospitals. Your own vet's answering machine probably also has suggestions.

Comment: @CrystalBarlow yes, and in many areas vets work together, offering 24/7 area coverage in rotating shifts with a central emergency hotline.