# My cat is afraid to eat

Tags: cats, behavior, feeding, fear

My 13 year old female cat has become afraid of eating, it started when she choked on a small treat 4 weeks ago. I have tried giving her food in different rooms and in different bowls, but she would eat a little morsel and then run away from it and then she stopped eating completely until I brought her a cooked chicken and for 3 days she ate but has stopped again.  before she would eat dry food morning and evening and a small portion of wet food in the evening. I really need help.  thank you

Comment: Related [How long can a healthy cat go without food?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/how-long-can-a-healthy-cat-go-without-food)

Answer (score 7):

Your cat could have all kinds of medical problems (esophageal problems, a dental abscess, kidney failure, etc.) I would take her to a vet.

Not to be confused with throwing up or coughing up a hairball, I have read choking (obstructed airway) in cats is very rare. I have never actually seen a cat choke, and I watch a lot of cats.

I am not sure how much your cat is actually eating. If a cat isn't eating its normal food it is super important to get them to a vet as soon as possible as that means something is very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be taking her to the vet ASAP.. while it's plausible that it's just a fear reaction to a one-off choking incident there could be a medical issue that's preventing her from eating properly and at the very least you need to rule that out as a first step.

If she's still drinking okay then you could try getting her some soup (the kind that's made for cats not humans!) e.g: https://www.purina.co.uk/cat/gourmet/product-range?filter=tags.texture.soup&gclid=CI2g_4Lj09QCFcqd7QodTw8PBA which will at least be getting her some nutrition but I still think  a vet needs to check her out.

Answer (score -1):

Try to get her soft foods such as wet food. There are two kinds of wet food. The kind which has chunks and the kind that looks smashed all together. The latter should be your choice.