# All of a sudden my cat is not eating, not drinking, walking slow and hiding. What's wrong?

Tags: cats, health

My cat, 8yrs old, was fine a few days ago, then quite suddenly he has become very anti-social, is hiding under the bed, in the closet or near the window. His meow is pained and doesn't like it when I touch him. He doesn't seem to be eating or drinking - and hasn't had any water in 24hrs it seems.

I'm going to take him to the vet but would be grateful if anyone could help figure out what's wrong with him.

---

**Update**:

He received pain medication, a water injection and medication that encourages appetite. The drugs have now worn off and he seems somewhat back to normal. I'm awaiting news of his urine and blood test.

It's still a bit of a mystery.

Comment: if a cat stop eating and drinking it is an emergency and if the cat starts hiding it is even more so,GET YOUR CAT TO THE VET NOW.

Comment: Related [How long can a healthy cat go without food?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/how-long-can-a-healthy-cat-go-without-food)

Comment: Any updates on your cat's test results. My 8 yr old just came from the vet for same reason and vet saw nothing based on tests but did blood work. He's back under the bed and will not respond to me or eat. He seemed fine up to yesterday and I saw just a little sign last night that he was off. I'm worried and trying not to cry. Thanks!

Comment: @Audrey you need to take your cat to the vet again not eating and drinking might cause liver damage in cats,and it can develop very fast.

Answer (score 8):

Your cat needs to see a veterinarian immediately. Only they can evaluate your cat to determine what is wrong.

A urinary obstruction is a major concern given the signs you have described, and the fact that your cat is a young to middle-aged male. This can be life-threatening, and will not get better without veterinary intervention. If your cat has a urinary obstruction, the longer this is left the more serious it will be.

Comment: Thanks. I took him to the vet and he was given pain medication, appetite stimulant and blood/urine tests. Waiting to see what's going on, but he's back to normal for now ... but still has yet to use the litter.

Answer (score 2):

Hiding and not eating, in and of itself, is merit enough for a trip to the vet; that fits with a cats "self-destruct" pattern (cats which are in a lot of pain or think they are terminal will hide themselves and stop eating).  Not drinking normally (some cats do drink less than others) is even more serious.

Anesthetic and other drugs sometimes can cause undesirable reactions afterwards.  If your cat is back to normal now, you might want to discuss with the vet what drugs were used, and seeing about avoiding those.

Comment: please read the question the cat did not eat got medication and then started to eat.