# My Siamese eats like a model

Tags: cats, health, diet, weight

My concern is my 2 year old long hair seal point female cat is light as a bird and in my opinion overly thin. She hides it well under a luxurious coat that in recent weeks seem lackluster at best. It seems to be by choice as I have exhausted any means to get her to eat more. She loses interest in a couple weeks in any brand, low cost or high (soft); she has a steady A grade hard always available, as well as water and treats. There’s been a marked change in her appetite but more so lately.

There has been a change in the household which I recognize as a contributor. A new member to the household. I found a roughly 5 month old female grey and white kitten on my steps apparently attacked or abused and in rough shape. Am I taking on too much for this group?

Are there any suggestions to help her reach a healthier weight and increasing activity? Is this just a phase (it’s been a issue to get her to sit down to a full portion for a long period). Her stools are regular and she's not vomiting, just little energy and engagement. Could it be jealousy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long can a healthy cat go without food?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/how-long-can-a-healthy-cat-go-without-food)

Comment: if a cat changes behaviour you need to take her to a vet,cats do not get jealous in the same way as people do but they can be scared if there is other cats in the house,it does not need to be more than the smell of an other cat that scares her.take her to the vet first and take it from there to find the cause for her to not eat.

Comment: Perhaps I forgot to mention that she observably eats and drinks, has regular vowel movements and isn’t throwing up. No I did as for jealousy or scared potato potato. Thx I’ll hold off

Comment: Especially the lackluster fur indicates that a trip to the vet would be reasonable. She could have some kind of parasite, vitamin deficiency or malnutrition. Some cats swallow inedible objects that then fill their stomach, which in turn reduces appetite. But in the end it could also be that the vet doesn't find a physical cause and she is just a picky eater...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you notice a change in appetite or the cat losing weight, a vet visit is in order.  It's often hard to tell with cats if there is something wrong, so anything different from what seems normal for them should get checked out.

Once medical issues are ruled out, then it's simply a matter of some cats are picky to the point that they won't eat enough if something isn't to their taste.  If this is what is going on, then really the only solution is to try various things to try to figure out something your cat likes more.  I have some suggestions of things you can try, such as:

1. Try different foods.  See if you can find a food appropriate to your cat that it really seems to like.  Wet foods also come in a variety of textures, so if you're trying wet foods, you might experiment with different textures too to see if it has a clear preference.
2. Change up what food you feed your cat every couple of weeks.  While a great many cats like routine and want the same old food every day, there are some cats that want variety and get bored if everything is the same.  I think this may be a more common trait in Siamese cats.
3. Change your cat's bowl.  Regular food bowls, to be honest, are terrible for cats to eat out of.  They usually have these corners in the bottom, making the food hard for them to get at.  Some cats also hate the feeling of sticking their head in a bowl at all, as their whiskers brush on the sides.  Our cat eats much better with [pet bowls designed to be very shallow with no corners,](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075KC97KC) when before he'd frequently just leave food uneaten.  If your cat tends to use its paws to eat, that's a pretty good indication that it hates its bowl.
4. You might try enticing your cat by putting a little bit of their favorite treat on top of their food.
5. Sometimes cats seem a bit less interested in food due to normal hairballs.  Hairballs of course are just a fact of life for cats, but it might make them less keen on eating.  You might want to watch if there's a pattern of not being interested in food, and if there's a hairball within 24 hours.  If such is the case, you might consult with the vet if there's anything you can do to help alleviate hairballs.  Of course there's the standard advice of brushing the cat more as well.
6. Play with the cat before mealtimes.  In the wild, it's normal for cats to get exercise by chasing down prey before they eat.  So some cats respond well to trying to simulate this routine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one! I most likely would encourage a trip to the vet to see if there are any underlying issues.

Our cat was quite thin. We took him to the vet and it turns out he has thyroid issues. He is on medicine now and is gaining weight!

Your cat could be a little depressed. I’ve heard some people say cats can be depressed. This could also require a trip to the vet. In the meantime though, I would encourage a little extra attention. Maybe keep her in the room with you and give her extra care. Monitor to see if that helps her.

I think the biggest thing to me, though, is there could be something going on. I know when cats don’t feel well they hide and seclude themselves. They don’t play a ton or eat a ton. I would highly encourage a trip to the vet to be sure!