# When should I take over from an injured mother cat who is not taking enough care of her kittens?

Tags: cats, injury

We have a cat which had 4 kittens very recently (they are approximately 2 weeks old).

Yesterday, she seemed apathetic and worried. We took her immediately to the vet, who informed us she probably got hit by a car or a bike. **She has a fracture on the base of her tail** (it doesn't move anymore, the vet told us she'll probably never move it again, it will be amputated if it doesn't heal on its own).

The vet told us she's probably not feeling any pain, merely some discomfort.

Since we brought her back from the vet, she's been staying on the couch all day long, and doesn't seem to go back to the kittens as often as she used to.

At what time should we start to :

- Insist on putting the mother cat back into the nest, so she takes care of the kittens ?
- Take care (feed, clean, ...) of the kitten ourselves, because the mother won't go back to them ?

While I keep in mind that all of that happened very fast (the accident probably happened less than 24h ago), I'm worried because the kittens are very young, and we should probably act quickly.

Comment: did your vet prescribe any medication for the mother cat,like steroids and painkillers.putting the food and water close to where the kittens are might help the mother cat to take care of her kittens.

Comment: Yes, the vet injected a painkiller, and gave us a medication in case she seems in pain. There is food and water near the nest. I put the cat on a cushion right next to the nest, but she might be still high from the injection of yesterday, so she still isn't moving

Comment: When you took her to the vet, did you mention the kittens at all?

Comment: The vet is aware the cat had kittens very recently. It has come up during our conversation. However I did not forsee the cat would react like this. Maybe the vet knew it would be okay, and discarded the subject, but I'd like to have some other opinions.

Comment: @ArthurAttout You wrote "she might be still high from the injection of yesterday". If she didn't nurse her kittens for a day, call the vet immediately! The kittens are extremely vulnerable to dehydration because of their tiny size and their only source of hydration is the mother's milk. For the same reason, they are even more at risk of ["Fatty Liver Disease"](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/5593/12501).

Comment: In the end, it all turned fine, the mother cat went back to the kittens after they started calling their mom in a more insisting fashion !

Comment: =[ please spay your cat and keep her safe from vehicles