# My cat is in pain when eating and even from drinking

Tags: cats, diet, dental-care, cat-food, pain

So for about 2 months we had noticed that my male cat would jump away from his bowl and act like something was stack in his teeth. We assumed at first that it was due to the dry kibbles he really like so we started to put a little water on his kibbles and it worked miracle. However 2 weeks ago i noticed that the jump scare when eating is starting again and its more like his really on pain this time. After jumping away the food, he would scratch his face like he wanted to remove something from his mouth(i would like to cry when seeing him on this condition), this also happens now even when drinking water or giving him wet treats. So last Friday we went to his vet and explained whats happening. The vet had an xray and its normal. However his tooth at the back has a swollen gum. His vet does not recommend to remove the tooth but just gave him pain reliever & antibiotic. However after going to vet my cat seems on lot more pain than before we went to vet and would only eat/drink normal when on pain reliever. should i seek 2nd opinion or just bring him again to our vet?? Do you have any same experience? Im so sad for my boy to be experiencing this :(

Comment: Why does your vet not recommend tooth removal?  It's true I'm not a vet, but it seems like a common treatment to remove the tooth if the gum around it is bad. Unless there's some other concern, like the cat is too old for anesthesia.

Answer (score 3):

If you just returned from the vet just yesterday, there's a high chance that the stress of the visit made the inflammation flare up. Also, antibiotics need a few days to take effect. I would wait 2 - 3 days before going to the vet again. As long as the painkillers work, you can give the antibiotics the time to do their magic.

However, not eating or drinking anything at all for more than 24 hours poses a risk of permanent health damage to cats. [Read this question for more information.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/5593/12501) So if your cat suddenly refuses to eat anything at all despite pain killers, I would either call the vet and ask for advice or get a second opinion from a different vet.

If you've treated your cat with antibiotics for more than 7 days without any sign of improvement, the treatment failed. It's time to call the vet again and talk about alternative treatment plans like removing the tooth.